# Searching Specific Column For Text - Then Adding Text Above IF Not Present

Tags: excel, vba

Depending on what the engineer experienced, they would press a button on their data recording application that would AUTOMATICALLY ENTER "Checkpoint" into the spreadsheet.

If that button was not pressed, there will be NO "Checkpoint" placed and the cells will remain empty.

In order to Calculate/finish my macro, I need to figure out how to add "Checkpoint" above the word "Signalized Intersection" BUT ONLY if "Checkpoint" already doesn't exist above the word "Signalized Intersection"

IMPORTANT NOTES: There will be ONLY THREE (3) "Signalized Intersections" on spreadsheet.

They are always in column G but never in the same row.

Some sheets will have NO "Checkpoints" at all, some will have TWO (2) "Checkpoints" etc.

There should ALWAYS be 3 Checkpoints in total (automatic or manually added) with 3 "Signalized Intersection" in total (aways automatically added)

EXAMPLE
G
1
2
3 (NEED MACRO TO FIND THE SIGNALIZED INTERSECTION BELOW, MOVE 1 CELL ABOVE TO THIS SELECTION - THEN CHANGE VALUE TO "Checkpoint")
4 Signalized Intersection
5
6
7
8
9
10
11 (THEN SEARCH AGAIN AND FIND THE SIGNALIZED INTERSECTION BELOW, MOVE 1 CELL ABOVE TO THIS SELECTION - THEN CHANGE VALUE TO "Checkpoint")
12 Signalized Intersection
13
14
15
16 Checkpoint 'Automatically Entered From Engineer' - (SINCE THIS ONE WAS ALREADY ENTERED, DISREGARD AND SHUT OFF.)
17
18
19 Signalized Intersection
20

Sorry for the lengthiness, if this isn't clear enough... I will take some screenshots to help clarify.

I have code written for other elements, so I will be adding this new code to it.

Comment: What is the problem though? What **specifically** is preventing you from coding this?

Comment: Ignorance. Only a 1 week 'veteran' of Excel VBA and not knowing the proper term/technique I am in need of makes my searches fruitless.

Comment: I am glad to do the code, if you or someone could guide me in the direction of the type of code needed to accomplish the above request.

Comment: For Row 19, you say that's "already entered", but "Checkpoint" is on row 16, not row 18, so that doesn't fit with your "check the row above Signalized Intersection" test....

Comment: Say Spreadsheet 1 was created by the program being used, the engineer did NOT have to 'press the button on recording app' for the recording sample. So there will be NO "Checkpoints" entered into row G. 

I NEED the a "Checkpoint" reference in order to calculate data, even if the "Checkpoint" being directly above "Signalized Intersection" is an arbitrary number.

Comment: OK then question becomes "how far above 'Signalized Intersection' do we look for 'Checkpoint' " ?  Up to the previous 'Signalized Intersection'  ?

Comment: Say Spreadsheet 2 was created by the program being used, the engineer DID have to "press the button on recording app" for this recording sample. So now there WILL be a "Checkpoint" entered into row G.

He only pressed that button once though, that happened at row 16 but the "Signalized Intersection" happened a few seconds/minutes later. So there is a gap between the two.

Since there was no button pressed for the first two "Signalized Intersection" data points, I need to code in the missing "Checkpoints".

Comment: It is always changing and there is no set limit to where a "Checkpoint" will reside within each "Signalized Intersection" datapoint.

When "Checkpoint" is added in manually/macro it will ALWAYS be directly above "Signalized Checkpoint." When the engineer instructs the program of a "Checkpoint" it will be entered between whatever "Signalized Intersection" data point is falls under.

If the engineer instructs 3 "Checkpoints" then no "Checkpoints" would need to be added.

Comment: 1: ScreenShot - Two Data Points I Manually Entered   
[link](https://postimg.org/image/if2x0d78z/)  
  
2: ScreenShot - One Checkpoint Engineer Entered VIA data recording app  
[link](https://postimg.org/image/8t9ck2g37/)  
  
3: ScreenShot - After my current macro is ran (with above data added)  
[link](https://postimg.org/image/8rzeqne9f/)

Comment: Are those two items the only text which will be present in that column, or could there be other content?

Comment: @TimWilliams [link](https://postimg.org/image/8rzeqne9f/) - That is the total text that will be in column G.

Comment: In that case see my answer below

Comment: @TimWilliams Tested, verified, and added into my existing code. Worked fantastic! Thanks much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Const VAL_SIG As String = "Signalized Intersection"
Const VAL_CHECK As String = "Checkpoint"

Dim bSig As Boolean, bCheck As Boolean, c As Range
Dim n As Long, sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ActiveSheet
Set c = sht.Range("G8")

Do While Application.CountA(c.EntireRow) > 0
    If c.Value = VAL_CHECK Then
        bCheck = True
    ElseIf c.Value = VAL_SIG Then
        If Not bCheck Then c.Offset(-1, 0) = VAL_CHECK
        bCheck = False
        n = n + 1
        If n = 3 Then Exit Do 'only expecting 3
    End If
    Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
```